# How to hide javascript errors throw in iFrames?

Tags: javascript, iframe, proxy

I have an iFrame that shows external web pages through one of my proxies that I control. But this proxy doesn't handle javascript properly most of the time, the external pages throws javascript errors. Javascript doesn't need to work as it's not important.

What can i do to hide these javascript errors? They are annoying and I may have more than one of these iFrames pointing to different external sources.

Comment: What kind of proxy do you mean? Could you inject code into the pages you load?

Comment: Curious if you ever solved this one.

Answer (score 1):

Could your proxy rewrite the HTML?  If you don't even care whether the HTML is valid, you can replace `<script` with `<!--script`, `/script>` with `/script-->`. and invalidate any event handler attributes e.g. replace `on[a-z]+=` with `*onnull=`.

The only JavaScript that could run then is within CSS expressions in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose just use the proxy to parse and replace all script tags and events. Since all of those tags have a regular pattern, you can just use regex to eliminate all script tags and all javascript events if not important.

Regex to remove script:

```
<script.*?</script>
```

Will remove all characters between script tags, but you should also remove the on x and javascript: addresses as well. More on this later.